# What is the right way to write these formulas in excel?

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am trying to build a formula for the following:

If the value in cell R52>0 then I want S52<(.10*R52) --> to return "under" OR if not, then S52>(1-.10)*R52 to return "over". If those are not met then I want to have excel return "fair".

However, I also need to add a special treatment for negative numbers -->

So if R52<0 I want to have the conditions R52>.10*R52 to return "over" OR if S52<(1-.10)*R52 to return "under". If not, then I want it to return "fair".

Hope someone can help with this. Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did it work? We can't suggest things intelligently without knowing what you've already done to accomplish this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(R52 > 0, IF(S52 < (0.1 * R52), "under", IF(S52 > ((1-0.1) * R52), "over", "fair")), IF(R52 < 0, IF(R52 > (0.1 * R52), "over", IF(S52 < ((1 -0.1) * R52), "under", "fair"))))
```

Outputs:

r   s   result

1   10  over

12  10  fair

-3  -10 under

-5  10  fair